# Splunk Data preview - Timestamp in milliseconds, Regex problems

Tags: regex, splunk

Im trying to parse out the timestamp in milliseconds with this Regex:

\d{7}/

Any idea why its not working?

```
 9281736 : COUNT IN 1003
Tx:   01 04 00 71 00 02 21 d0                              ...q..!.
Rx:   01 04 04 00 08 0a 28 7c f8                           ......(|.
   9282136 : COUNT IN 1003
Tx:   01 04 00 c9 00 02 a1 f5                              ........
Rx:   01 04 04 00 08 00 00 7a 46                           .......zF
   9282536 : COUNT IN 1003
Tx:   01 04 01 2d 00 02 e0 3e                              ...-...>
Rx:   01 04 04 00 00 ff ff fa 34                           ........4
   9282936 : COUNT IN 1003
Tx:   01 04 01 f5 00 02 60 05                              ......`.
Rx:   01 04 04 00 23 00 00 0a 4e
```

I preview with "Unsorted data" and get timestamp error message - "Failed to parse timestamp. Defaulting to file modtime."

Comment: you're after the `9281736`? There's no reason `\d{7}` shouldn't match that, other than you're missing the closing `/` to finish off the pattern.

Comment: Yes, I'm after 9281736.

Comment: I like the joyous tone of `\d{7}/` but I believe you [don't need `/` regex delimiter here](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/6.1.4/SearchReference/regex). If the simple `\d{7}` isn't working, can you show how you're calling the regex?

Comment: I'm using the "Data Preview" option in Splunk. Previewing as "Unsorted data" and prefaceing the timestamp pattern with the regex command.

Answer (score 0):

I think the Regex should be `\d{7}`, not `/\d{7}`. Note the slashes!